# Oracle Precision

Tags: oracle, database-design, numbers

I want a number to take values between -7.2E-75 to +7.2E+75.   How should I specify precision and scale for the NUMBER.  (The scale range is 1 to 38 and precision is -84 to 127).

If there is any other way to accomplish this please suggest.

Comment: just asking, cant you use them as varchar ? and If you want to calculate you can use to_number

Comment: @Moudiz - why on earth would you think storing numeric data as strings is a good idea?  It's bad enough with have to deal with such things in legacy systems without design new applications that way.

Comment: Not sure why this has a close vote as "too broad".  Seems a very focused question to me (even before I edited it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeric values you propose are well within [the limits of the Oracle NUMBER datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/limits001.htm#i287903).

Do you *need* to specify a precision?  Defining a column as just NUMBER is allowed:

```
SQL> desc t1
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER
 COL2                                               NUMBER
 COL3                                               NUMBER
 COL4                                               NUMBER

SQL> insert into t1 (col1, col2) values ( -7.2E-75, +7.2E+75);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If it's the range bounds which are bothering you, you need to define a CHECK constraint to enforce the rule.

---

> "Suppose i want COL1 to take 123456766675544.344546567676, with NUMBER as datatype its failing"

Failing?  How?  That value works fine for me (same table as before):

```
SQL> insert into t1 (col1) values ( 123456766675544.344546567676);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

So, please provide more details, such as the error message.

> "When i fire the above query it is showing just 123456766675544,"

That sounds like a display issue.  The right values are being inserted.  Check this out:

```
SQL> set numwidth 50
SQL> select col1 from t1
/
  2  
                                              COL1
--------------------------------------------------
7.20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E+75
                      123456766675544.344546567676

SQL>
```

In this case, setting the NUMWIDTH to its maximum allowed value ( in SQL*plus) allows us to display one value but the other is still too big, and so we have to use scientific notation.

Comment: Suppose i want COL1 to take 123456766675544.344546567676, with NUMBER as datatype its failing.

Comment: When i fire the above query it is showing just 123456766675544, but i want it to take value after decimal also it should be complete 123456766675544.344546567676.

Comment: Sorry that i said failing,it's not failing, i am not getting desired results by setting datatype to NUMBER.